# set up performance monitor for a service

Tags: windows-server-2003, performance-monitoring, microsoft-project

On a windows server 2003 server, i have a particular service that's causing me a lot of heartache.  I was wondering if there was a way to set up performance monitor to track information for the service?  the specific service i'm interested in is Project Server Views Notification Service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can track the specific instance under the "Process" object corresponding to the PID of the program you're interested in tracking to get general statistics about the process (CPU, memory, IO). Unless the program exports its own performance counters, though, that's about all you're going to get. (There are "Thread" counters, too, but they're probably not going to tell you anything.)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you want project server health monitor:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/project-server-it/project-server-health-monitor-tool-HA001164272.aspx